# Computer freeze on wake-up (Win 10 / Win 11)

Tags: windows, freeze, sleep

So I have a small desktop computer ([Zotac BI329](https://www.zotac.com/product/mini_pcs/zbox-bi329)), which normally works fine. I didn't used it for several weeks, and now I noticed, once it goes to sleep, it can't resume properly.

So basically:

- it goes to sleep
- click on power button or use mouse or keyboard or WakeUpOnLan
- desktop turn on (power red light change to green)
- but screen is off, keyboard light would not change, wifi or disk light are off

What I tried so far:

- Uninstall all recent updates (some although can't be uninstall)
- Update bios (lookin for drivers on constructor website I saw there was a newest version for win 11 support)
- Migrate windows 10 to 11 (keeping my files)
- Full reinstall of Windows 11
- Rollback to old Graphic driver (one from constructor, from 2017)
- Update all drivers from constructor website
- Windows updates up-to-date
- Remove all usb (keyboard, mouse, external disk)
- sfc /scannow --> no error
- Windows memory diagnostic (extended one) --> no error
- Tunes power management settings (disable fast-boot, hybrid sleep, hibernation)
- Looked at events, don't see anything particular apart windows was turned off unexpectly

I'm not sure what next to do, apart from that it works totally fine. But as I used mostly as a home NAS without a screen, not being able to have it sleep and wake-up on lan is really annoying ...

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a hardware problem. try removing rams(if u have 2 in laptop/computer) or change your ram. if it still does not work then try changing SSD/HDD. make sure to keep a backup of your data.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I don't know if I there is 1 or 2 RAM, but I can check that.
For the SSD I don't have a spare one, so don't want to buy another one if that's not sure it's the issue ...

This computer is also less than 2 years old

Comment: Checked inside and sadly only one RAM so can't check if that's really the issue

Comment: I didn't even find the SSD. Assume it's behind the motherboard but then I would have to remove the warranty seals to check there